# jQuery cannot convert to a proper object that my controller can read

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in jQuery that converts any form into a JSON object. I want to keep this as generic as possible, because I need to use it multiple times.

```
var getFormObject = function (form, nameOfObject) {
    var unindexed_array = form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });
    var object = { nameOfObject: indexed_array }

    return object;
}
```

My controller accepts an object with the name of 'object' like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditObject(MyObject object)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I use Ajax to post the object, unfortunately it doesn't work, because my json object array is invalid. This is due to `nameOfObject`.

If I do the following instead:

```
var object = { 'object': indexed_array }
```

I'm good to go.. however, I don't really want to do that! Neither do I want to use FormData().

Therefore, how can I achieve what i want to achieve, and thus keep my function as generic as possible?

Comment: You don't need to put the data in an object named to match the argument in the Action. Assuming you're using the default model binder, then just sending the `indexed_array` directly should work.

Comment: Wait.... `MyObject object` really???

Comment: @Tân ofcause not. I dont use the default modelbinder no.